# SSRS: Calculate the Max Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I use SQL Server Report Builder.

I have got 20 machines and I calculate the scrap data for these 20 machines. 
In my query it looks like:

```
SELECT SUM(case when ScrapName = 'Blown wheel' then scrapUnits else 0 end) AS BlownWheel,
       Sum(case when ScrapName = 'Blown bell' then scrapUnits else 0 end) AS  BlownBell,
       Sum(case when ScrapName = 'Produced' then scrapUnits else 0 end) AS Produced
```

And to get the scrap I did a calculation in SSRS:

```
=SUM(Fields!BlownWheel.Value) + SUM(Fields!BlownBell.Value) / SUM(Fields!Produced.Value)*100
```

This calculation gave me the correct value.

My **Problem** now is that I must create a new report and in this report I would like to show **one** of these 20 machines which produced the maximum value of scrap.

I have done this manually in Excel before. And now I would like to create it as a Report.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @M.JAY what is the structure of your scrap table?. I think you can group by machine in your query, create a calculated field in SSRS and using the max function to get the value you need.

Comment: I tried it but this shows me all machines I would like to see only one machine.